# How to position a label using css relative to an absolute positioned input box

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position a label using only html/css relative to an absolute positioned input box.

The html is being generated by code, and it outputs an input box like this:

```
<input type="text" style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 200px;"></input>
```

The label then has a class with 4 possible values, left, top, right and bottom.

```
<input type="text" style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 200px;">
    <label class="top">Client Forename</label>
</input>
```

If the label is positioned right then the label needs to go to the right of the input box etc, etc.

What I know of CSS is that the parent normally has a position of relative, with the child as an absolute allowing the child to be positioned anywhere in relation to the parent.

But because the input is already being set to absolute, I can't work out how to achieve this.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You really shouldn't have a `label` *inside* an `input`

Comment: Yes I agree, as you can tell I'm clutching at straws to solve this.

Comment: @MichaelBellamy parent does not need to be `position:relative`, it just need to be a positioned element. i.e you can absolutely position an element with a parent having position `relative` , `absolute`,`fixed` etc other than `static`.

Comment: @nick - what am I doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/8Hg26/1/

Comment: The end tag for `<input>` elements is forbidden. They are EMPTY. You do not have a label inside an input. You have a label after an input and then an invalid end tag.

Comment: @MichaelBellamy have a look at James' answer below. Having a label inside an input is invalid and the browsers will render them as siblings rather than the label sitting inside the input, so you need to wrap them both in a common parent as suggested by James!

Comment: @Tilwin Joy - Thanks very much - that could solve my problem!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An `input` can't contain other element and as such can't have other elements positioned relative to it.  You can however wrap both elements in a common parent and absolutely position that.  Then the `label` can be positioned absolutely in relation to the parent element.

http://jsfiddle.net/KeW3R/1/

**New HTML structure:**

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;">
    <input type="text"/>
    <label class="right">label</label>
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 50px;">
    <input type="text"/>
    <label class="left">label</label>
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 100px;">
    <input type="text"/>
    <label class="top">label</label>
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 150px;">
    <input type="text"/>
    <label class="bottom">label</label>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
label{
    position: absolute;
}
.right{
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}
.left{
    top: 0;
    right: 100%;
}
.top{
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
.bottom{
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much James - this has put me on the right tracks.

I forgot to include the width and the height of the input boxes too so I've modified your version slightly to accommodate this. It needs a few tweaks, but I'm nearly there. http://jsfiddle.net/57GAr/